# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden, when downloading videos using Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

I have been trying to download files using `urllib.request.urlretrieve`, for example, this [Video](http://dl2.mihanpix.com/Serial/24/S07/24_S07_E11.mkv), but it doesn't work; it works only for pictures. Is there any better way to do that?

The error message I get is:

> File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 588, in http_error_default raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @dash2 Here is it ** File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 588, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden **

Comment: Great, so put that in the question. See [ask].

Comment: I've improved your question for you. I edited it to include the error message in the question body (relevant information should not be put in the comments). I also shortened the title but it should, ideally, be even more concise.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Thanks.